# Delete a change to an object in a higher layer in Dynamics 365 for operations

Tags: axapta, dynamics-365, dynamics-365-operations

I am upgrading a custom solution done on the ISV layer in Ax2012 to D365.  I’ve finished resolving the code conflicts.  During the build of my CodeMergeSolution, some compile errors were thrown.

Included in my modelstore from Ax2012 was the InventTrans form.  During the conflict resolution stage, I found that our customization done on the InventTrans in the Ax2012 form would not be needed in D365.  I want to thus remove the customization, and use the standard D365 form instead.  But the form is still showing as being customized on isv layer.  And the form is throwing compile errors, because it has references to (among others) a CostValue display method – that was standard in Ax2012, but does not exist in D365 anymore.
To resolve these compile errors, I need to completely remove the isv layer on this form.
How do I do that?
Right-clicking on the form in design view, has the “Remove all customizations” greyed out.
Right-clicking on the elements I want to remove also has the “Delete” greyed out.

In all the previous versions of Ax, if you’d wanted to delete changes made on a layer, you would log into that layer and simply delete that object, which restored the object as it was done in the lower layers.  What is the process now in D365?

Comment: Are you working in a project associated with the model containing the customization?

Comment: Yes I am.  I was able to remove the customisation by deleteing the object from the Project, thanks.